# Errors when using a Ruby On Rails scaffold with a data type of integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, scaffolding

I am learning Ruby On Rails. I am on a shared hosting with Ruby version 1.8.1 and Rails version 2.3.10.  I am working my way through a tutorial at http://railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app?version=2.3#top and at one point in the tutorial it has me run:

```
script/generate scaffold Micropost content:string user_id:interger
```

The tutorial is using the default database, SQLite3.  The command works and I use **rake db:migrate** to create the database.  I can view the page listing the microposts (which is empty), but when I try to add a micropost (microposts/new) I get an error **undefined method `user_id' for #<Micropost:0x7f710e4988e8>**  After doing some testing on my own it seems I experience the problem by using the data type of **interger**.

While I understand that using a scaffold is not the best way of building a ruby on rails, I'm just beginning and would still like to know why I am experiencing this problem to help me better understand how rails works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you mistyped `integer` as `interger`?

Comment: You are, of course, correct. Thanks for helping me with this very obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have spelled **integer** wrong three times in this question, so I would guess that you  got it wrong in the code too. The correct spelling is **integer**.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked the question at dictionary.com...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should always check for typos. does your table for Microposts have the column 'user_id'
you can look it up in the migration file

Comment: The table did not have the 'user_id" column which, I am sure, is because I don't know how to spell.  Once I used the correct spelling all was well.